# How to get Stack Overflow request key

Tags: wordpress, stackexchange-api

I have a website that I need to integrate the Stack Overflow profile widget into using WordPress. So, please tell me the procedure and what are the things I require and how to follow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is "stackoverflow profile widget"?? You can research about the API at [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to integrate Stackoverflow Profile Widget to your site, you can do it in 2 ways.

1. Use Stackoverflow Profile API from https://stackapps.com/.
2. Use the plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/stackoverflow-profile-widget/

Comment: iam new this can you help on stackoverflow profile API

Comment: This may help you: https://github.com/RookieOne/StackOverflow-API.
But better to use the plugin.

Comment: ok i installed the plugin but after installation it was asking stackoverflow request key.how to get stackoverflow request key?

Comment: Ude this link: http://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register. For this you need to register in Stack Apps.
But for this plugin request key is optional.